# I got error while printing object's value after I update the state in react

Tags: reactjs, undefined

This 'products' is an array of objects. All the objects have a property named 'total'. After I update the state, if I tried to print current state value  'total' in componentDidUpdate() it works fine but, if I tried to print previous state value 'total' then it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    console.log(this.state.products[0].total) //works fine
    console.log(prevState.products[0].total) //error

    console.log(this.state.products[0]) //works fine
    console.log(prevState.products[0]) //works fine
```

}

Comment: you check console.log(prevState) then tell me what a output is

Comment: share us complete code then we understand easily

Comment: Yes, I got it. This products array is empty for the first time. That's why it is showing undefined.

Comment: Yeah.exactly right

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full logic but `prevState` could contain empty array of `products`

`prevState.products[0]` would then return `undefined`

Can you add following if statement?

```js
if(prevState.products[0]) {
  console.log(prevState.products[0].total) 
}
```

Comment: Oh, I got it. When the first time it renders, products array is empty that's why it is showing undefined.